# Natural skeleton horses?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm in a survival world with cheats, but have only used the command toggle downfall, other than that no cheats, and I found a group of naturally spawned skeleton horses! It looked like there was just one, but when I right clicked it it burst into four skeleton horses, they were all tamed after me getting on them one time and able to be taken back home with a saddle. There had been a sort of recent thunder storm, this probably happened at least an hour after the storm. They were standing in water just on the edge of a jungle and extremely close to a jungle temple... does anyone have any explanation??? they spawned naturally and there were no skeletons. also I'm on easy mode

Comment: Based on your question, I removed the cheats tag (since you're specifically not asking about cheats, just playing on a mode where cheats are allowed) and added the Minecraft tag (because I'm sure with "survival world", "toggle downfall" that you're talking about Minecraft).  If those changes were incorrect, you can revert them by clicking "edited X time ago" over my name in your question, or re-edit the question to make it clearer by clicking the edit button in the bottom left corner of the question.

Answer (score 4):

The skeleton trap horses are a new mob introduced in 1.9 [snapshot 15w38a](https://minecraft.wiki/w/15w38a).
From the wiki:
When a player approaches to within 10 blocks, the following will happen:

```
Lightning strikes the horse.
The horse will become skeletal if it isn't already.
The horse becomes tame.
The horse becomes fully grown (if a baby) and the breeding cooldown is reset.
IA skeleton is spawned riding the horse.

If on peaceful, the Skeleton will not spawn, while the Horse will.
The skeleton has damage immunity for 3 seconds.
The skeleton will not despawn since they have the tag PersistenceRequired set to true.
The skeleton will be wearing an iron helmet, unless it randomly spawned with some other headgear.
The skeleton's bow and helmet will be enchanted as if on an enchantment table at level 5–22.
    The level is higher depending on regional difficulty; on Easy it will always be a level-5 enchantment.

Three additional skeletal horses with riders will be spawned in the vicinity.
```